# php mysql insert select multiple with where clause

Tags: php, mysql, insert-select

I have a following

```
Table1 : userid, who, share, date  :: id is auto increment and primary key
```

I would like to build a query to check if record exist and insert new record if is empty.
How to build this in a single query and insert multiple records using a single query

```
data to inser ('a1','a2','a3','a4'), ('b1','b2','b3','b4'), ('c1','c2','c3','c4'), .......
```

Comment: are there any unique keys? what should happen if there are conflicting records? should it be ignored? there is a construction of insert like this:

`insert ignore into <table> values(),(),();`

Answer (score 2):

1. Create [`UNIQUE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html) index on column that you want to be unique
2. Use [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) to insert unique data and ignore not unique

Answer (score 0):

You could use REPLACE statemement that works just like INSERT only it doesn't do anything if the row already exists:

```
REPLACE INTO table ...
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Answer (score 0):

You should take careful look at [mysql `INSERT INTO` documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html).

How to insert "on no exists" is simple. Let's say you want combination of `user,who,share` to be unique and use latest date. Update your table and create [`UNIQUE KEY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html) on those fields:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD UNIQUE KEY (user, who, share);
```

Normally inserting the same combination would cause error but using `INSERT IGNORE` (link above) would silently ignore error:

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table1 (user,who,share,date) VALUES ( 1, 2, 3, NOW());
```

You may also [force key to update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) on insert:

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table1 (user,who,share,date) VALUES ( 1, 2, 3, NOW())
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE date = VALUES(date);
```

And inserting multiple values at once, again the first link:

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```